# How do I print to a Canon Pixma iP7250?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I'm trying to use my Canon Pixma iP7250 Printer on Ubuntu 20.04.  It is connected via USB.  When I try to give the command `lsusb`, it detects everything but the problem is when I try to print something.

It won't print anything. When I check the list of printer jobs there is nothing there. It's like the printer is recognized by the OS but still doesn't print.

On another PC running Ubuntu 18.04, I have no problem at all with printing.

I noticed as well that all the color profiles are missing.  I don't know why. I tried installing `michealgruz` ppa but nothing changed.

Comment: Give what you get for `systemctl list-units "ippusbxd*" | grep service`

Comment: make sure you don't have usb and ethernet cable plugged in at same time.
My Cannon wouldn't print

Comment: i did the command you ask but therew is not any output should i use sudo instead of nothing?

Comment: [Canon's support website for the Pixma iP7250](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/printers/inkjet/pixma_ip_series/pixma_ip7250.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)) publishes a 64 bit linux driver (deb).  Have you installed it?